# Open365 will not install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

We have tried installing Open365 on Ubuntu 16.04 to no avail.

When attempting to install via dpkg we get the following error:

```
sudo dpkg -i libqt4-core_4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package libqt4-core.
(Reading database ... 221375 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libqt4-core_4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt4-core (4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-core:
 libqt4-core depends on libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqt4-dbus:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.
 libqt4-core depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqt4-network:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.
 libqt4-core depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqt4-script:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.
 libqt4-core depends on libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqt4-test:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.
 libqt4-core depends on libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqt4-xml:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.
 libqt4-core depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqtcore4:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-6+b1.

dpkg: error processing package libqt4-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-core
```

This also fails when attempting to use gdebi, and the Software Center.

Note all attempts to install the dependencies manually fail as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the issue. Seems like the developers are on to it.
https://support.open365.io/index.php/en/forum/englishsuport/25-problem-with-client-install-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts?limitstart=0

Answer (score 0):

After some research we have concluded that this is a known issue that should be remedied in the next release for Ubuntu 16.04 updates:

[Bug #1573206](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206)